# Boost::Asio HTTP Server extremely slow

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I'm currently trying to create a http server using Boost.Asio, I made it like this [HTTP Server 3](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.http_server_3).

Currently I just read the Request and always return an OK Message. So nothing special or time consuming.

The Problem I come across is, running the Server with 12 Threads (16 cores @ 2.53GHz), the server handles arround 200-300 requests per second.

I did the same in C# using HttpListener, running with 12 Threads, it handles arround 5000-7000 requests.

What the heck is Boost.Asio doing?

Using Instrumentation Profiling with Visual Studio get following "Functions With Most Individual Work":

```
Name                         Exclusive Time %
GetQueuedCompletionStatus               44,46
std::_Lockit::_Lockit                   14,54
std::_Container_base12::_Orphan_all      3,46
std::_Iterator_base12::~_Iterator_base12 2,06
```

**Edit 1:**

> ```
> if (!err) {
>   //Add data to client request
>   if(client_request_.empty())
>     client_request_ = std::string(client_buffer_.data(), bytes_transferred);
>   else
>     client_request_ += std::string(client_buffer_.data(), bytes_transferred);
>   //Check if headers complete
>   client_headerEnd_ = client_request_.find("\r\n\r\n");
>   if(client_headerEnd_ == std::string::npos) {
>     //Headers not yet complete, read again
>     client_socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(client_buffer_),
>         boost::bind(&session::handle_client_read_headers, shared_from_this(),
>           boost::asio::placeholders::error,
>           boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)); 
>   } else { 
>     //Search Cookie 
>     std::string::size_type loc=client_request_.find("Cookie"); 
>     if(loc != std::string::npos) {
>     //Found Cookie
>     std::string::size_type locend=client_request_.find_first_of("\r\n", loc);
>     if(locend != std::string::npos) {
>       std::string lCookie = client_request_.substr(loc, (locend-loc));            loc = lCookie.find(": ");           if(loc != std::string::npos) {
>         std::string sCookies = lCookie.substr(loc+2);
>         std::vector<std::string> vCookies;
>         boost::split(vCookies, sCookies, boost::is_any_of(";"));
>         for (std::size_t i = 0; i < vCookies.size(); ++i) {
>           std::vector<std::string> vCookie;
>           boost::split(vCookie, vCookies[i], boost::is_any_of("="));
>           if(vCookie[0].compare("sessionid") == 0) {
>             if(vCookie.size() > 1) {
>               client_sessionid_ = vCookie[1];
>               break;
>             }
>           }
>         }             }
>     }         }
>     //Search Content-Length
>     loc=client_request_.find("Content-Length");
>     if(loc == std::string::npos) {
>       //No Content-Length, no Content? -> stop further reading
>       send_bad_request();
>       return;
>     }
>     else {
>       //Parse Content-Length, for further body reading
>       std::string::size_type locend=client_request_.find_first_of("\r\n", loc);
>       if(locend == std::string::npos) {
>         //Couldn't find header end, can't parse Content-Length -> stop further reading
>         send_bad_request();
>         return;
>       }
>       std::string lHeader = client_request_.substr(loc, (locend-loc));
>       loc = lHeader.find(": ");
>       if(loc == std::string::npos) {
>         //Couldn't find colon, can't parse Content-Length -> stop further reading
>         send_bad_request();
>         return;
>       }
>       //Save Content-Length
>       client_request_content_length_ = boost::lexical_cast<std::string::size_type>(lHeader.substr(loc+2));
>       //Check if already read complete body
>       if((client_request_.size()-(client_headerEnd_)) < client_request_content_length_) {
>         //Content-Length greater than current body, start reading.
>         client_socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(client_buffer_),
>             boost::bind(&session::handle_client_read_body, shared_from_this(),
>             boost::asio::placeholders::error,
>             boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
>       }
>       else {
>         //Body is complete, start handling
>         handle_request();
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

**Edit 2:**

Client used for testing is a simple C#-Application which starts 128-Threads each iterate 1000 times without any Sleep.

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(BaseUrl);
req.Method = "POST";
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("{\"method\":\"User.Login\",\"params\":[]}");
req.GetRequestStream().Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
req.GetRequestStream().Close();
```

Comment: Rewrite code simply. It's not optimal.
request_parser in example parse per byte and push_back it to string, without any reserve. There is also some undocumented issue with asio::strand.

Comment: Difficult to tell without seeing some real code.. have you tried profiling it? Also, have you compiled it with any optimisations?

Comment: This is often a problem with leaving Nagle turned on.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039224/poor-boost-asio-performance/2039378#2039378

Comment: @ForEveR even if request_parse isn't optimal, it doesn't explain why is it so extreme slow.

Comment: @Nim Have a look at the Example HTTP Server 3

Comment: @janm Also tried that with acceptor_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay(true));

Comment: I don't understand - 'GetQueuedCompletionStatus' is a blocking 'pop' call on the IOCP queue - why is it doing so much work?

Comment: Boost Asio performs bad with many threads. consider please:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234750/c-socket-server-unable-to-saturate-cpu

Comment: Please add a description of the HTTP client used for testing.

Comment: @free_coffe see Edit 2

Comment: @RaphaelH ok, but what C# APIs does it use to send the HTTP requests? Is it small enough to paste the code used for each iteration?

Comment: @free_coffee I dont think that matters cause in my Test's against a C# Http Server he handled enough.. But in the Edit there are the lines ;)

Comment: @RaphaelH it might matter if both the C# client and server use HTTP keepalive. AFAIK the Boost.Asio HTTP example closes the socket after every request.

Comment: While the abstraction provided by Boost.Asio will contribute to some delays, the HTTP protocol is processed within user mode.  On the other hand, `HttpListener` is tailored to a specific OS and the protocol is processed in an HTTP stack within kernel mode.  It may be interesting to compare the results of the Boost.Asio application with one that uses a `TcpListener` and processes the HTTP protocol in user mode.

Comment: @TannerSansbury Just tried using TcpListener and Parsing Request like in C++, but still I reach 4500 requests per second in C#. For me it seems like the C++ Boost.Asio does everything single-threaded..

Answer (score 6):

The reason for the slowness probably is that Boost::Asio HTTP Server 3 example always closes the connection after each response, forcing the client to create a new connection for each request. Opening and closing connection on every request takes lots of time. Obviously, this could not outperform any server that supports HTTP/1.1 and Keep-alive (basically, doesn't close client connection and allows client to reuse it for subsequent requests).

Your C# server, System.Net.HttpListener, does support Keep-alive. The client, System.Net.HttpWebRequest, also has Keep-alive enabled by default. So, the connections are reused in this configuration.

Adding keep-alive to HTTP Server 3 example is straightforward:

1. inside connection::handle_read() check the request if client requested Keep-alive and store this flag within the connection
2. change connection::handle_write() so that it initiates graceful connection closure only when client doesn't support Keep-alive, otherwise just initiate async_read_some() like you already do in connection::start():

   ```
   socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer_),
       strand_.wrap(
           boost::bind(&connection::handle_read, shared_from_this(),
               boost::asio::placeholders::error,
               boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)));
   ```

And don't forget to clear your request/reply and reset the request_parser before calling async_read_some().

Comment: As I wrote already in the main comments, I tried using .net TcpListener and parsing the Request like I did in C++, but still I reach easily 4500 requests per second. And there I also closed every single connection.

Comment: I still don't get what is the point in testing performance of an HTTP server without keepalive. None of the web servers work that way because it's too slow.

Comment: I understand your objection, but it is about the confusion that .Net is that faster.

Comment: If you have any interest in comparing apples to apples, either use keepalive both in C# and in Boost.Asio, or disable it in both of them.

Comment: As I said, I tried comparing it using a TcpListener instead of HttpListener, which I think does not support HTTP Keep Alive.

Comment: *bump* @RaphaelH - were you able to try out vond's suggestion?

Comment: @quixver Not yet. But if you're interested in it, give it a try on your own! Maybe you'll figure something out

Answer (score 2):

it seems that `client_request_.find("\r\n\r\n");` is called repeatedly -- hunting for the end tokens from the beginning of the string each loop. use a starting position position. such as `client_request_.find("\r\n\r\n", lastposition);` (using bytes_transferred)

its possible to use  `asycn_read_until(  ,"\r\n\r\n");` found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until.html)

or `async_read` which should read all (instead of some).

Answer (score 0):

About HTTP server 3 example. Look at the [request_parser](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server3/request_parser.hpp) source code. The methods parse/consume. It is really not optimial cus it getting data from buffer byte-by-byte and working with each byte; pushing into **std::string** using **push_back** and so on. Its just an example.

Also, if you are using **asio::strand** notice that it uses a mutex t lock "[strand implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/boost/asio/detail/strand_service.hpp)". For HTTP server its easily possible to remove **asio::strand** at all, so i recomment to do this. If you want to stay with **strands** - to avoid delays on locking you can set those defines at compile time:

```
-DBOOST_ASIO_STRAND_IMPLEMENTATIONS=30000 -DBOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_SEQUENTIAL_STRAND_ALLOCATION
```

Comment: Just removed all "strand"'s, but still extremely slow. I'm not using the tutorial request_parser, added the code that I'm using.